# What are ''dirty nodes'' in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx

In my program, I used the **Imageview** class, added it to the **list**, and finally added the list to the **Pane**, from which the list does not change. When the program is running, I need to change the position of the loaded image by calling **setLayoutX()** and **setLayoutY()**, and this process continues. The result is that the program has some problems. The first is to throw exceptions such as **ArrayIndexOutBoundsException** and **NullPointerException**. In addition, some images will not change their position. When checking the exceptions, I find that this should be related to the fact that these nodes are classified as "dirty nodes". So I want to know why they are classified like this.

Comment: In general, "dirty" means that something has been modified and not yet written to some back store (or redrawn).

Comment: So the setLayoutX/Y() modifies something, meaning that these methods need to be synchronized?

Comment: The errors indicate a issue unrelated to "dirty nodes": You're probably updating the GUI from a thread other than the javafx application thread.

Comment: You should not use new threads. Once nodes are displayed you always need to use the javafx application thread to modify the scene (which is the thread input event handlers should run on). Please post a [mcve] of your problem since it's hard to tell how dirty states would result in the error. In fact "dirty" in this case most likely means that the node has been updated before after the last layout pass.

Comment: Without posting more information you probably won't get an answer though. (It's more likely to get the question closed...)

Comment: @fabian I tried a lot and I thought you were right, "You're probably updating the GUI from a thread other than the javafx application thread."I didn't completely do this. In addition, I want to know if there will be problems if I modify it too frequently? I think it is.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you have forgotten of put your UI code inside JavaFX Application Thread. I recommend you to put your UI code inside `Platform.runLater(() -> { /* your JavaFX code. */ }` or to use a [Task](http://aprendendo-javafx.blogspot.com/2014/08/threads-e-javafx.html) to separate what must be or not in a JavaFX Application Thread.

If this didn't work for you, the problem can be a possible bug of the JavaFX reported by one of develops in a comment on impl_updatePeer method and Region class:

```
// TODO I think we have a bug, where if you create a Region with an Image that hasn't
// been loaded, we have no listeners on that image so as to cause a pulse & repaint
// to happen once the image is loaded. We just assume the image has been loaded
// (since when the image is created using new Image(url) or CSS it happens eagerly).
```